im getting these errors while installing mingw from msys2 what should i do
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-3.2.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gettext-0.22.4-3-any.pkg.tar.zst.sig' from mirror.nju.edu.cn : Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.

im getting these errors and i dont know what to do i was just following the instructions on the vs code website (btw im new to programming)
i tried to install mingw thru msys2 and i was expecting it to install but these errors popped up

Just try the same command again a few times. If this doesn't work, are you perhaps behind some sort of a network filter (school network, etc)?

yea im using a school network it does have a firewall i dont get a data connection in my dorm i tried using --disable-download-timeout but then also an error came

error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crt-git-12.0.0.r264.g5c63f0a96-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn port 443 after 10029 ms: Timeout was reached

Either you have a really slow connection or you have something in your network slowing it down, like for example a firewall that download and scans the download before giving it to you and in the mean time keeps your connection going at a slow rate.
Normally this works unless it takes that system longer than the configured timeout in the client software (I presume pacman in this case).
In case the download is cached retrying the command some time later might help.
But pacman has an option --disable-download-timeout which will probably do the trick (though the download may still take quite a while).

i tried using --disable-download-timeout but another error came im also on a school network as i dont get data connection in my dorm

error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crt-git-12.0.0.r264.g5c63f0a96-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn port 443 after 10029 ms: Timeout was reached

it did install after that but when i tried to run a piece of code it showed me this

The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1.

@YodaSkywalker If it did install eventually, you should create a new question for you new problem, and provide more details (how exactly you configured VSC and so on).

@YodaSkywalker What happens if you use a web browser to go to https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/ ? That may give you a clue to the proble.
But also - as @HolyBlackCat said - if the solution mentioned above did allow pacman to download, please accept the answer and ask new issues in a new post.
